# what changing my code from label to JLabel work?

Tags: java, swing

this is my origin code and it doesn't work:

```
//this code is to draw a panel and when you click "start", the Panel p2 changes color

      JFrame frm = new JFrame("1");


frm.setBackground(new Color(150,130,110));
      frm.setSize(400,300);
      frm.setLocation(200,200); 
      Panel p1=new Panel();
      frm.add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
      final Panel p2=new Panel();
      frm.add(p2,BorderLayout.EAST);
      Panel p3=new Panel();
      frm.add(p3,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      p1.setLayout(b2);
      p2.setLayout(b3);
      p3.setLayout(g1);
          });
      Label l1=new Label("max:"+sum);
      p2.add(l1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
      Label l2=new Label("blood:"+blood);
      p2.add(l2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      bu1.setBackground(new Color(200,100,100));
      p2.setBackground(new Color(100,200,100));
      l1.setBackground(new Color(100,100,200));

frm.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

and i find out that if i can make it work just by changing :

```
  JLabel l1=new JLabel("max:"+sum);
  p2.add(l1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  JLabel l2=new JLabel("blood:"+blood);
```

can make it work,so i wonder why?

is it related to the

```
  final Panel p2=new Panel();
```

or difference between swing and awt?

Comment: 1) Change Panel to JPanel. 2) ***Read*** the Swing tutorials. I can speak from experience by telling you that you shouldn't guess at this stuff as you'll invariably guess wrong.

Comment: May I ask what isn't working? I'm on a phone, so I can't run this, but do both labels not show? You obviously aren't showing all the code (p2 must be final cause its being used in anonymous class; its not the fault). @HovercraftFullOfEels He's adding the component to a heavyweight panel, which all top-level Swing containers are heavyweight aswell. Why would this cause a problem?

Comment: @VinceEmigh: without a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to guess what could be specifically wrong, but as a general rule, he should stick with the light weight components, especially if he wants his pop up menus to behave well, and especially if later on he wants to do Swing graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Swing and AWT are entirely different component layouts. Swing is a lightweight framework provided by java, while AWT relies more on native libraries and is considered "heavyweight". Mixing the two frameworks is almost always buggy, which is likely why you had problems.

Comment: Something I dont understand is that he's adding a heavyweight component to a heavyweight container (panel). Since JFrame is also heavyweight, why wouldnt something like this be allowed?

Comment: `JFrame` is Swing, `Panel` is AWT. I'm not really an expert of working between the two GUI's but I'd have to imagine intermixing them at some level is what causes it.